# How to set x, y for a textElement in JasperReports depending on if above textElement is empty. And if non-empty show it down to the that textelement

Tags: jasper-reports

Requirement:

If *firstName* and *lastName* is non empty. Show this at x=125, y=3 coordinates.
And show address down to it at x="125" y="26" coordinate. This is working fine.

Problem: If firstName/lastName are empty, Then we need to move the address element up and show it at x=125, y=3 coordinate itself.

This is where I am stuck. Please help me.

Please refer my jrxml file below:

```xml
<frame>
    <reportElement key="frame-462" positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="50" width="390" height="70"/>
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Now">
        <reportElement key="textField-844" positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="125" y="3" width="264" height="23"
                       isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[(!$F{firstName}.isEmpty() && !$F{lastName}.isEmpty())]]></printWhenExpression>
        </reportElement>
        <textElement markup="styled">
            <font fontName="Verdana" size="12"/>
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression>
            <![CDATA[$F{firstName} +  "<style pdfFontName='Helvetica-Oblique' size='11'>" + $F{lastName} + "</style>"]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Now">
        <reportElement key="textField-843" mode="Transparent" positionType="Float" x="125" y="26" width="264"
                       height="42" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
        <textElement markup="html">
            <font fontName="Verdana" size="12"/>
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{address}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
    <staticText>
        <reportElement key="staticText-1249" positionType="Float" x="2" y="2" width="108" height="21"
                       isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Left">
            <font fontName="Verdana" size="12" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
        </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[ Address:]]></text>
    </staticText>
</frame>
```

Comment: Please note: giving both text element same x, y coordinates and setting isStretchWithOverflow for the 1st textElement still show overwritten texts.

Answer (score 3):

You have already set the `isRemoveLineWhenBlank` attribute, which will remove the empty space left by the `textField`. However, JasperReports cannot collapse vertical space unless that space is completely clear. If there is another element occupying the same line (in your case the `staticText` element), the empty space will be preserved. This is a bit like playing Tetris in reverse; You have to get rid of all of the blocks before the line will disappear.

Putting report elements into frames modifies this behaviour slightly. It is only the width of the parent frame that needs to be clear, instead of the width of the whole report. Therefore, by putting your name and address fields into a separate frame, the space occupied by the name field can collapse despite being aligned horizontally with the static text. I have modified your code snippet to demonstrate this:

```
<frame>
    <reportElement key="frame-462" positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="50" width="390" height="70"/>
    <frame>
        <reportElement x="126" y="0" width="264" height="70"/>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Now">
            <reportElement key="textField-844" positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="3" width="264" height="23" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[(!$F{firstName}.isEmpty() && !$F{lastName}.isEmpty())]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement markup="styled">
                <font fontName="Verdana" size="12"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{firstName} +  "<style pdfFontName='Helvetica-Oblique' size='11'>" + $F{lastName} + "</style>"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Now">
            <reportElement key="textField-843" mode="Transparent" positionType="Float" x="0" y="26" width="264" height="42" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
            <textElement markup="html">
                <font fontName="Verdana" size="12"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{address}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </frame>
    <staticText>
        <reportElement key="staticText-1249" positionType="Float" x="2" y="2" width="108" height="21" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Left">
            <font fontName="Verdana" size="12" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
        </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[ Address:]]></text>
    </staticText>
</frame>
```

Comment: Alex K is right, Monika you should accept his answer

Comment: I like an analogy with Tetris, it helps me and makes me smile at once :)